# Wildcard for arbitrary depth

Tags: wildcards, recursive

I want to use `grep` where paths are arbitrary depth under the directory `/path/to/dir` and has the file name `foo`. I thought that the wildcard for arbitrary depth is `**`, and I tried

```
grep some_pattern /path/to/dir/**/foo
```

but it seems to be matching only files where the `**` part represents a single directory depth like

```
/path/to/dir/bar/foo
```

How can I match paths for arbitrary depth that is under the directory `/path/to/dir` and has the file name `foo`?

Comment: Is this a difficult thing? I expected that only I didn't know.

Comment: An alternative is ``cat `find . -name foo` | grep some_pattern``

Comment: @Harvinder better use `find . -name foo | xargs grep some_pattern` since the number of files might otherwise exceed the maximum size of command line arguments. Even better: `find . -name foo -print0 | xargs -0 grep some_pattern`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use zsh. In the zshexpn(1) man page, Section "Recursive Globbing":

> A pathname component of the form '(foo/)#' matches a path consisting of
>   zero or more directories matching the pattern foo.
>
> As a shorthand, '**/' is equivalent to '(*/)#'; note that this therefore
>   matches files in the current directory as well as subdirectories.
>
> [...] This form does not follow symbolic links; the alternative form '***/'
>   does, but is otherwise identical.

This also means that `**` doesn't include hidden directories (whose name starts with a dot) by default. If you want to match them, either set the `GLOB_DOTS` option or use the D glob qualifier:

```
grep some_pattern /path/to/dir/**/foo(D)
```

With bash, you need to explicitly set the `globstar` option to make `**` work:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Comment: zsh is not available everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to vinc17's suggestion, you can use `--include` combined with `-r option`, something like:

```
grep -r --include \foo some_pattern /path/to/dir/*.
```